# how to perform 'SELECT TOP X FROM TABLE' type queries with DB2 / dashDB

Tags: dashdb

I would like to perform the equivalent of `SELECT TOP 1 ...` query in db2 / dashDB:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM customers
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can achieve this query using the `FETCH FIRST x ROWS ONLY` statement, E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM customers FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way on dashDB, and more easy for my opinion is to use the 'limit n', E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 1
```